# How to play .WAV sounds in c++

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, codeblocks

How can I play a .WAV sound in a simple c++ console aplication? I am using code blocks on windows xp.I need the most simple and efficient way.Thanks in advance :D
Btw:CAn i play 2 sounds at the same time?Like background music and sound effects?

Comment: If you want to play lots of sound effects; try PCM as it's totally uncompressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Simple Direct Media Layer (SDL) library along with SDL_Mixer library. http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL_mixer:Tutorials:Playing_a_WAV_Sound_File
Here's an excellent tutorial: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson11/index.php

Comment: hmm is it open source?I mean i can use it anywhere with no restriction?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Audiere](http://audiere.sourceforge.net/) or [Mikmod](http://www.bitplanet.de/mikwin/index.html) if you are after playing music or such sounds. If you are after more game oriented, or realtime behavior, you might be better off with [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), which offers [callbacks](http://osdl.sourceforge.net/main/documentation/rendering/SDL-audio.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the PlaySound API - you indicated that you have a .WAV file, and PlaySound is tailor made for playing .Wav files.